# How to Print An Odd Number of Backslashes in Python

Tags: python, escaping

I need to print a string as part of a list that has 3 backslashes in it in Python. However, this is not appearing to be as simple as I expected.

```
print ["\\\"]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment> 
EOL while scanning string literal: <string>, line 1, pos 13
```

Any string that has an odd number of backslashes will do this because Python is escaping the quote. So I tried escaping myself:

```
print ["\\\\\\"]
['\\\\\\']
```

which is 6 backslashes. Not what I wanted. This has stumped a few of us around the water cooler.

Comment: Your second example is correct, but you are seeing the `repr` of the string within the list that you're printing.  Try `print "\\\\\\"`.

Comment: This is a python FAQ for those who want some more background.

https://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash

Comment: I realize that now g.d.d.c. Looks like my eyes (i.e. my python interactive shell) were deceiving me.

`print [len(x) for x in ["\\\\\\”]]
[3]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'\\\\\\'` is a string contain 3 backslashes. You can see that there are 3 characters in the string by applying `list` to it:

```
In [166]: list('\\\\\\')
Out[166]: ['\\', '\\', '\\']
```

`'\\'*3` would also work:

```
In [167]: list('\\'*3)
Out[167]: ['\\', '\\', '\\']
```

Or since

```
In [169]: hex(ord('\\'))
Out[169]: '0x5c'
```

you could avoid the need to escape the backslash by using `\x5c`:

```
In [170]: print('\x5c\x5c\x5c')
\\\
```

Comment: this is the right answer really ... I just didnt want to explain how string repr vs string value works (+1)

Answer (score 2):

```
print r"\\\ "
```

would work I think (`r` indicates a literal string)

(as pointed out in the comments you cant end with a backslash in raw strings ...(so I added a space))

If you didnt want the space you could

```
print r"\\\ ".strip()
```

Comment: A raw string can't end in a backslash.

Comment: added a space :P was my bad not thinking :P

Comment: anyways I like answer